# How are BuckleScript library names generated?

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

Where do libraries get the name we use in for example `open BsReactNavigation`?

For example, there is no module in [bs-react-navigation](https://github.com/callstackincubator/bs-react-navigation) named `BsReactNavigation`?

So how does reason know what we are referring to when we say `open BsReactNavigation` in a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace module is generated when the `namespace` property in `bsconfig.json` is set to `true`. It is generated based on the `name` field of `bsconfig.json`, converted to PascalCase. That is, the first letter is capitalized, the letter following every dash is capitalized and the dashes are removed. E.g. `my-wacky-library` becomes `MyWackyLibrary`.

Some [not so good documentation](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/build-configuration.html#name-namespace) exists (which claims the feature is almost mandatory. It is not. While the reasoning is good, the feature is not, so most people use either just a single module or manual namespacing instead)